# How can i create only one Player object in Network game Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I try to create network game in Unity3D. By default, when the game started, the Network manager instantiate `Player` object each `Gamer`. But I want who is the Host gamer, it would be create player object. The others must ask himself 'Am i host?' The answer is 'no' and then ask himself again 'Where is the named of PlayerObject?' answer here 'it is.' So  how can I instantiate only one `Player` object?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine who the host is by using Network.isServer. You can use Network.Instantiate to instantiate a player on all clients' machines, but the owner will be whoever instantiated it.

Comment: Can you send me any document how can i use these ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-isServer.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Instantiate.html

Comment: @NurullahCelik I commented them in :)

Comment: Thank you, i will be try that :)

Comment: that not works correctly, i have one problem. When i instantiate with Network.Instatiate function. I can't see clients player objects in hierarchy. is that normal ? But i must be found in hierarchy that game object

Comment: @NurullahCelik It should show things in the hierarchy. Does it throw any errors? Can you post your code?